# MeshMemory causing constant spikes

Tags: unity, performance, optimization, memory-efficiency

I have a ready-to-launch application, cleaning everything right now. I have these strange spikes on `Mesh Memory`.

The best part of it is that this view below is from a static menu screen, where there are no meshes. I don't even interact with it.

Can this be caused by meshes import options or something like that?

[image]

Comment: Is this an inspection of a build or are you inspecting while running in the editor?

Comment: It's an editor. Already tested it on two Android devices - same thing.

Comment: Are you using a canvas for the menu? There may not be any 3D meshes, but everything is a mesh at some level (whether a UI generated mesh gets counted here I don’t know). Still, that seems like a lot of memory just for a canvas.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1385077/massive-memory-leak-in-not-saved-unity-20171.html Seems like a huge memory leak, probably caused by TextMesh Pro :(

Comment: A memory leak would see a continuous increase in memory usage over time. These spikes area indicative of something else. Can you do a deep profile and see what's different in those frames as far as method calls?